# How to accelerate time?

Tags: science-fiction, physics, time-travel

Something in a spaceship, a box,  an area in the space, whatever, that experiences a faster time than the rest of the universe.
The opposite of the well known twins paradox.

How could be that the twin that remains in earth is younger than the other who went through this yet to describe experience?

Is this possible within our current understanding of physics?

Comment: The satellites on orbit who kindly provide the GPS/Glonass/Baidou/Galileo signal free of charge for your phone to use to tell where is the closest shawarma shop [experience time flowing faster](https://www.astronomy.ohio-state.edu/pogge.1/Ast162/Unit5/gps.html) than it does for your phone on the ground. (By about 38 microseconds per day.) The clocks on the satellites actually compensate for this so that you can reliably find that shawarma shop.

Comment: I know,  but that is to little difference. The Earth generates too little time dilatation. One way to do this would be to place the planet Earth orbiting a super massive object (like in the film Interstellar) and the object far away.  But the idea is not to move Earth from where it is.

Comment: Not really sure if the atual 'paradox' is understood. The twin who stayed back on Earth traveled faster,relative to the other twin and should have been younger, not older. in effect, relative to each other, both twins have to age exactly the same, depending on which frame of reference you use.

Comment: @JustinThymetheSecond: They would not have aged the same, because the two reference frames are not equivalent. One of them stayed in an almost inertial frame all the time, while the other most definitely did not, because the spacecraft had to accelerate in order to return; this is the assymmetry which explains the different ages.

Comment: @JustinThymetheSecond - just lending additional weight to AlexP's response; the twin paradox is fully understood, and has to do with fixed inertial frames of reference.  It's also been conclusively demonstrated with atomic clocks.

Comment: @AlexP This is all baffledegab hype cherry-picked from relativity and other theories that tries to adjust reality by the isolated application of fragmants of obtuse theory to prove that one twin would age more than the other, but the main paradox still remains sound. The work with atomic clocks explains gravitational time dilation. The ONLY thing that can dismiss the twins paradox cleanly is that there actuall IS a universal 'zero' frame of reference (the locus of the Big Bang) that all others are determined from.

Comment: The twin paradox isn't actually as well understood as you might think. If it's all about inertial frame of reference, then there could never be a such thing as "deceleration." There has to be a universal zero, or all acceleration would be acceleration. That said, it's doubtable that traveling at said universal zero would have a meaningful effect on time dilation. We're already close enough to it that the minor adjustment wouldn't make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

This is not practical within our current understanding of physics. To do it, you would need to accelerate the place where the slow twin is staying to relativistic velocities, then slow it down again. Since that seems to be a planet, the job is rather hard.

That only matters if you're trying for reasonably "hard" science fiction. If you're dealing with quite soft SF, like *Star Trek*, or fantasy with scientific-looking trappings, like *Star Wars*, you need only bluff your way through this idea.

However, you *need to make it relevant to the story*. Complicated things that aren't relevant to the story are distracting, and readers/viewers tend to look at them harder, and spot holes in them. Then suspension of disbelief tends to break down, and engagement with the story is lost.

Comment: [Stellar engines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stellar_engine) to move a whole solar system (and thus orbiting planets) are within known physics, but not at relativistic speeds.

Answer (score 0):

## The solar system is in a dyson sphere, and is travel ling extremely fast.

We can slow down time, so the solar system has been converted to a dyson sphere, and is moving through space extremely quickly, enough to cause time dilation. The spaceship is not moving that fast, and so time goes much faster on it.

Comment: The only thing which matters is the *relative motion* of two observers, in this case the spaceship relative to the Dyson Sphere. It doesn't matter how fast the Dyson Sphere is moving relative to anything else. Assuming the spaceship launched from the Dyson Sphere, at launch their relative velocities are 0 and the spaceship accelerates away from the Dyson Sphere. This is just the Twin Paradox.